# Is it possible to customise the section index list in a UITableView (such as font)?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

UITableView gives you the ability to edit colors of the section index list with properties such as

```
var sectionIndexColor: UIColor? { get set }
var sectionIndexBackgroundColor: UIColor? { get set }
```

Is it possible to edit it in other ways?
Looking for Swift implementations.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to adjust it if you're okay with accessing private properties.
I believe this would pass store approval but don't take my word for it.
Here are the properties/functions you would be able to access. https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UITableViewIndex.h

I've tested changing the font with the following and it worked.

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in
        if let tableViewIndex = self.tableView.subviews.first(where: { String(describing: type(of: $0)) == "UITableViewIndex" }) {
            tableViewIndex.setValue(*Insert Font Here*, forKey: "font")
            self.tableView.reloadSectionIndexTitles()
        }
    }
}
```