# Can I make the index list letters of a UITableView larger?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my iOS app I have a tableview with an index list on the right hand side (vertical listing of A-Z).

If I press a letter in the index list, my tableview will jump to that section. For example, if I press 'S', it will jump to the 'S' section in my tableview.

Everything works great.

However, the index list letters (i.e. the vertical column which holds the letters on the right hand side) is a bit small. Can I make this larger?

Have not found anything from searching.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45833132/is-it-possible-to-customise-the-section-index-list-in-a-uitableview-such-as-fon?r=SearchResults&s=1|93.6134 but note that there is no public API to change anything other than the colors of the index list.

Comment: You'll need to make your own... searching for `custom uitableview section index` returns a few results. If none fit your needs, they'd at least be a good starting point.